# Firebase returns complex object instead of the data I want

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm using angularfire2 and trying to pull data from my firebase project sitting in a Realtime Database. Instead it keeps pulling a weird and highly complex object from my db.

```
people: AngularFireList<Object[]>

constructor(
public userService: UserService,
public authService: AuthService,
private route: ActivatedRoute,
private location: Location,
private fb: FormBuilder,
private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
private afs: AngularFirestore,
private http: HttpClient,
private db: AngularFireDatabase
) {
    this.people = this.db.list('/thisisatest');
    console.log(this.people);
}
```

Here's how my firebase is setup.

[image: Firebase RealtimeDatabase setup]

But I'm getting this crazy complex object returned! Where is my data?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `db.list()` can not return the list directly, firstly because it returns a class that allows you to do more complex tasks (`.add()`, `.remove()`, `.update()`), but also because the data is not yet downloaded.

Angular works a lot with observables, and that is the preferred way to keep data connected in angular. I can't explain Observables for you in this post, but I can quickly show you how we can log the values it gets (as it gets multiple values over time, as the database updates)

First, to get the observable of the value, we can do

```
this.db.list('/thisisatest').valueChanges(); // This returns the observable
```

As described here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#retrieve-data
Most likely, in your app, you'll want

```
this.people = this.db.list('/thisisatest').valueChanges();
```

If you want to console.log the values for debugging, you can do (in addition to assigning it to `this.people`)

```
this.db.list('/thisisatest').valueChanges().subscribe(people_value => {
  console.log('people:', people_value);
});
```

It would still be worth reading more on Observables, as they are not the easiest to grasp :)